# jquery.jqGrid.min.js:(dynamic code evaluation: code injection)

Tags: jqgrid

Hi i am using Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.1.1
After run in HP Fortify i facing this issue in 13 and 17 line.
issue 1: jquery.jqGrid.min.js:13(dynamic code evaluation: code injection)
issue 2: jquery.jqGrid.min.js:17(dynamic code evaluation: code injection)

need help to solve this by today or tomorrow

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all Guriddo jqGrid JS has open source, but it's **not** free. You can see the prices and the licence agreement [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). You used "free-jqgrid" tag (see [the description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info)), which corresponds **another fork** of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop. I can't help you with Guriddo jqGrid and can forwar you only to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js). In any way you should use non-minimized version of js file for any reports.

Comment: You can try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which is compatible with old jqGrid in versions <=4.7. You can load it from CDN directly (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)), from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) or [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid).